# Como declarar e instanciar um vetor Double?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando preencher um vetor de Double com 1's, porém não sei como declarar e instanciar a variável.

```
double betaParcial[] = null;

// 'linha' seria o tamanho do vetor, e pode assumir qualquer numero (ex.: 3 ou 4)
for(int i=0 ; i<linha; i++) { 
    betaParcial[i] = 1.0; // Ocorre o erro
}
```

Comment: O que significa 1's??

Comment: Tipo, vetor[5] = { 1,1,1,1,1}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente:

```
double betaParcial[] = new double[linha];
```

Comment: Bah, era isso mesmo, obrigado.